# how to return a user id from an express backend server

Tags: reactjs, express

Working on the login for a stock application. When the user typs in their email and password the users ID which is currently hardcoded in my server will be returned to the console. I will use that ID to save it to local storage to keep the session alive and allow access to my protected routes. I am unable to return the user ID with my current logic.

Backend

```
let users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        userName: 'user1',
        email: 'abc@email.com',
        password: 'abc'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        userName: 'user2',
        email: '123@email.com',
        password: '123'
    }
]

    app.post('/api/auth', (req, res) => {
        let userResult = users.find(user => user.email === req.body.email);
        if (userResult) {
            if (userResult.password === req.body.password) {
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: true,
                    user: users.id
                })
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: false
                })
            }
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({
                message: false
            })
        }
    });
```

Front end

```
handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const request = {
            email: this.state.userEmail,
            password: this.state.userPassword
        }
        if (this.state.userEmail === '' || this.state.userPassword === '') {
            alert('Enter Username and Password')
        } else {
            this.setState({userEmail: '', userPassword: ''})
        }
        axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/auth`, request)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.message) {
                    console.log(res.data.user)
                    //add user ID to local storage.
                    //this.props.history.push('/dashboard') Re-directs to dashboard page!!!
                    this.setState({isAuth: true})
                } else {
                    alert('Invalid username or password')
                    this.setState({isAuth: false, userEmail: '', userPassword: ''})
                }
            console.log(res.data.message)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
```

Comment: what does get returned from the post call?

Comment: The message returns true in the console if the user exists

Comment: what does res.data.user current return then?

Comment: res.data.user returns undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found if after reading through it a few times, you are returning users.id not userResult.id

```js
if (userResult.password === req.body.password) {
  res.status(200).send({
    message: true,
    user: userResult.id
  })
}
```